# Return 0 price for grouped product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I'm newbie to Magento, I'm just testing product price module so by using following code

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()); ?>
```

It return me price properly for Simple product but it's not working for Grouped product So I Googled it and found following code snippet

```
<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice(),true,false); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice(); ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false); ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true); ?>
```

But all above code return me price as 0 , So can please anybody suggest me what can I do to get price which work for both Simple & Grouped product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped Product is a combination of products, you can't directly call `->getPrice()` on Grouped Products.

Use below code instead:

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(PRUDUCT_ID);

if($product -> getTypeId() == "grouped"){
    $grouped_product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped');
    $groupedParentId = $grouped_product_model->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
    $_associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);

    foreach($_associatedProducts as $_associatedProduct) {
        if($ogPrice = $_associatedProduct->getPrice()) {
            $ogPrice = $_associatedProduct->getPrice();
        }
    }

    $ogPrice = number_format((float)$ogPrice, 2, '.', '');
    echo $ogPrice;
}else{
    echo $_product->getFinalPrice();
}
```